# Does linux permissions works only when linux running?

Tags: linux, permissions

In linux(and in windows) we can set read/write/execute permissions for files and folders.

But does these permissions work only on OS level(means that only linux guarantee this)?

If i will connect to HDD or SSD without OS, will these permissions work?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [unix.se] or [su]. This site is for programming related questions, not general OS or computer support. The [help] has more info.

Comment: see this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30283/are-file-permissions-set-in-unix-linux-effective-in-windows-or-any-other-os

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i will connect to HDD or SSD without OS, will these permissions work?

No. The permissions are enforced by Linux. If there is no Linux, there is noone to enforce those permissions.

You don't even have to go through the hassle of trying to scrape the data off the device without using an OS. You can just boot your *own* Linux where you know the superuser password, and use your superuser privileges to access the files.

This works the same way in Windows.

Or any other environment, really. Java has `private` access, but if you are able to circumvent the Java compiler, e.g. by getting access to its *output* rather than just its input, then you can circumvent that, too.